# Convert X Coordinate from one Resolution to another

Tags: c++

usually i would do this to convert from one resolution into another:

```
int newX = (x / oldResolutionX) * newResolutionX;
```

But this time i can't use it and i can't get my head around the math (never was really good at math, forgive me please). Anyways, my Resolution is 1280x720 and i want to convert a point like (720/360) to this:
[Picture of new Resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diljB.png)

The Width is 854, Height is 720, so i don't have to do a conversion for the y coordinate. But here's the (for me) tricky part: 0 is not the actual 0. X starts at -107 and ends at 747. Could you guys explain to me how i can convert (720/360) from 1280x720 into this Resolution? Thanks in advance and sorry for being bad at math...

Comment: If there's a 107 or 747 offset, then just add those..

Comment: So, you need just an X mapping from  [-107...747] to [0...1280]?

Comment: @JesperJuhl (720 / 1280) * 854 + 107 = 587.375, but should be 320. Or i don't understand what you mean by offset

Comment: @Stefan yes ._.

Comment: It's actually simple. Let's say we have `y` and we need to map into a new vale `x` then: `x = (y - ymin) / (ymax - ymin) * (xmax - xmin) + xmin`. In your case `ymin = -107, ymax = 747` and `xmin = 0, xmax = 1280`.

Comment: @DimChtz you mean like this: `int newX = (x - 0) / (1280 - 0) * (747 - -107) + -107;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need a linear mapping from [0...1280] to [-107...747], leaving y untouched.

```
int newX = (int)((x / 1280.0) * 854.0) -107
```

So, whats happening here?

- x will vary between 0 and 1280.
- if x == 0: (0/1280) * 854 will be 0 and the result equals -107.
- if x == 1280: (1280/1280) * 854 = 854:  the result will be 747

Some remarks:

- the `.0` is used to force a floating-point type.
- the `(int)` is to cast it back to a integer

Comment: Doesn't work for me, if i try to get the middle of both Resolutions: `printf("X.1: %i - X.2: %i\n", 320, cX1(640));` it returns `X.1: 320 - X.2: 1119`

Comment: I am not sure I understand: the image, with width [-107...747]; half the coordinate would be `320`. `((320 + 107) / 854) x 1280 = 640`: halfway the target resolution

Comment: I have a 1280x720 screen and i have to convert it into 854x720. Middle on my screen is (640/360) on the other thing it has to be (320/360). The second screen is basically 640x720 but they added 107 on both ends of the x coordinate. SO center of x is 320, but it goes from -107 to 747

Comment: ah, than it's the inverse XD .. hold on

Comment: it is! Thank you :)